# using php namespaces correctly

Tags: php, namespaces

I have just started rebuilding my app i made to use namespaces to make future development easier and so we can reuse class names.

basically my code is as follows.

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use core\marketing as marketing;
use core\security as security;
use core\structure as structure;
use core\data as data;

include 'marketing\cleanurl.php';
?>
```

As soon as I run this I get the following error:

> Warning: include(marketing\cleanurl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/index.php on line 27 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'marketing\cleanurl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/index.php on line 27

My directory structure matches the namespaces as that is what I read on the net.

Now if I change the include to match the directory i.e.

```
include 'core/marketing/cleanurl.php';
```

I get the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_NS_SEPARATOR or ';' or '{' in /var/www/twiggled/core/marketing/cleanurl.php on line 4

This all worked when I was just using require_once to call all the classes but found this limited expansion of the system and made changes more time consuming and wanted to use namespaces as they have always been great in other languages I have used.

Comment: can u post content of cleanurl.php

Comment: The first error is what happens when you design the namespace separator to look like the path separator from the wrong plattform. (You are on a Unix filesystem requiring the forward slash, but used the Windows backslash.)

Comment: @mario the namespace separator is correct per PHP documentation. The problem appears to be with how you are including the cleanurl file.  That seems to be where the slash might be the problem. Change to "marketing/cleanurl.php" if you are on a unix system and make sure that you have not omitted a semicolon somewhere.

Comment: Namespaces and file paths are entirely separate, they do not work together. The first error is a regular problem with wrong file paths. The second is a normal syntax error, for which we'd have to see the file it occurs in.

Comment: Your `cleanurl.php` probably misses a semicolon right after the `namespace core\marketing` declaration.

Comment: Thanks you was right about the semicolon I knew it was something simple in the clear url. As for the other comments whats the point in namespaces if you have to include the full qualifying directory path that is pointless may as well stay with require once is less code that way.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.

I see an issue here if I have to include the full directory path what is the point in the namespaces just seems to make the code 10 times more bulky than it needs to be.

I wanted to move to namespaces as I was told in 2 tutorials it followed the directory structure and allowed for better arcitetured code and makes it easier to change things in the future but if you guys are right then require_once as I was using in the first place is a much cleaner way to write my code. So may as well leave it as it is and just make up some new class names.

Comment: Namespaces help you to namespace your code (duh). There are a ton of discussions on what namespaces are good for, search for them. You should use *autoloading*, then namespaces and file paths are extremely useful together. Look into using Composer (google it).

Comment: No need to be rude. The way most of the tutorials I have seen talk about namespaces they make it come across that namespaces allow you to write less code in but in actual fact when you get right into it you have to write a lot more to do the same job. Seems to cause more issues than it solves from what I have seen. Thanks for your comments but I will stick with what I have. Thanks

Comment: I wasn't rude, just trying to cram facts into a comment. Namespaces are important for large projects. Yes, you write a little more code, but this is amortized in better structured, decoupled, separated and better maintainable code later.

Answer (score 2):

Since OP asked for it, here's an updated answer using autoload.

Note: Such a complex construct wouldn't be needed for the ease of task, of course. However, This is just an example how things *play together* (autoloading, requires, static methods etc).

### Bootstrap / Autoload

**/var/www/somedir/Twiggled/bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
namespace Twiggled;

require_once __DIR__ . '\Common\AutoLoader.php';

$autoloader = new \Twiggled\Common\AutoLoader(__NAMESPACE__, dirname(__DIR__));
$autoloader->register();
```

**/var/www/somedir/Twiggled/Common/AutoLoader.php**

```
<?php
namespace Twiggled\Common;

/**
 * PSR-0 Autoloader
 *
 * @package    Common
 */
class AutoLoader
{
    /**
     * @var string The namespace prefix for this instance.
     */
    protected $namespace = '';

    /**
     * @var string The filesystem prefix to use for this instance
     */
    protected $path = '';

    /**
     * Build the instance of the autoloader
     *
     * @param string $namespace The prefixed namespace this instance will load
     * @param string $path The filesystem path to the root of the namespace
     */
    public function __construct($namespace, $path)
    {
        $this->namespace = ltrim($namespace, '\\');
        $this->path      = rtrim($path, '/\\') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    /**
     * Try to load a class
     *
     * @param string $class The class name to load
     *
     * @return boolean If the loading was successful
     */
    public function load($class)
    {
        $class = ltrim($class, '\\');

        if (strpos($class, $this->namespace) === 0) {
            $nsparts   = explode('\\', $class);
            $class     = array_pop($nsparts);
            $nsparts[] = '';
            $path      = $this->path . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $nsparts);
            $path     .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';

            if (file_exists($path)) {
                require $path;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Register the autoloader to PHP
     *
     * @return boolean The status of the registration
     */
    public function register()
    {
        return spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'load'));
    }

    /**
     * Unregister the autoloader to PHP
     *
     * @return boolean The status of the unregistration
     */
    public function unregister()
    {
        return spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'load'));
    }
}
```

### Package files

**/var/www/somedir/Twiggled/Core/Helper/Strings.php**

```
<?php
namespace Twiggled\Core\Helper;

class Strings
{
    // Note: Eventhough the method use a global PHP function name,
    // there is no problem with it - thanks to namespace.
    public static function str_replace($str) 
    {
        $str = preg_replace('/\s/', '_', strtolower($str));
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z_]/', '', $str);
    }
}
```

**/var/www/somedir/Twiggled/Core/Marketing/Cleanurl.php**

```
<?php
namespace Twiggled\Core\Marketing;

use \Twiggled\Core\Helper\Strings as HelperStrings;

class Cleanurl 
{
    const BASE_URL = 'http://example.com/';
    public $cleanPath;

    public function __construct($str) 
    {
        $this->cleanPath= HelperStrings::str_replace($str);
    }
}
```

### Load and use it..

**/var/www/somedir/index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin');

// Bootstrap the package / register autoloader
require_once __DIR__ . '\Twiggled\bootstrap.php';

use \Twiggled\Core\Marketing as Marketing;

try {
    $obj = new Marketing\Cleanurl('$This w-ork5s!');

    // prints 'http://example.com/this_works'.
    echo Marketing\Cleanurl::BASE_URL . $obj->cleanPath; 
} 
catch (\Exception $e) { }
```

Comment: Thanks but no point in using namespaces if I am going to have to use require once was trying to move from that way to namespaces for better arcitecture. Does not seem possible though with PHP. O well.

Comment: I don't get your point?! 1.) Note, that this is a simplified example based on the info you gave. But even if you use an autoloader (what I highly recommend), you still need to include the autoloader (ie require it). 2.) Remember, one essential point of namespaces is to avoid name collisions between your own code and internal PHP and/or third-party classes/functions/constants. Essentialy, a namespace in PHP is nothing more than a hierarchically labeled code block holding regular PHP code. So even if you don't use an autoloader but go with includes instead, namespaces still avoid name conflicts.

Comment: I was using an autoloader it looked like this does it seem right            function _autoload($className)
{
 $filename = str_replace('\\', '/' , $className) . 'php' ;
 require_once $filename;
 }

Comment: @Paul See my updated answer for an example using autoloading.

Comment: Thanks for your help after re watching the tutorials and re-reading everything with your example I now get it. Will give it a go this weekend and see how it goes. Thanks again.